# .h note: previous declaration of 'QueueADT' was here typedef struct { } *QueueADT;

Tags: c, debugging, header, queue, abstract-data-type

I would like to know how to solve the errors for redefinition of the typedef struct QueueADT.

**error messages**

```
gcc -std=c99 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra  -c queueADT.c
queueADT.c:22:3: error: 'QueueADT' redeclared as different kind of symbol
 }*QueueADT;
   ^
In file included from queueADT.c:9:0:
queueADT.h:23:21: note: previous declaration of 'QueueADT' was here
 typedef struct { } *QueueADT;
                     ^
queueADT.c:30:1: error: unknown type name 'QueueADT'
 QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) ) {
 ^
queueADT.c:30:10: error: conflicting types for 'que_create'
 QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) ) {
          ^
In file included from queueADT.c:9:0:
queueADT.h:44:10: note: previous declaration of 'que_create' was here
 QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) );
          ^
```

The .h file has a definition if not compiling which is the queueADT and que_create

```
#ifndef _QUEUE_IMPL_
typedef struct { } *QueueADT;
#endif

QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) );
```

Now I am not sure how to define the QueueADT struct and the que_create from the .c file here

```
#ifndef _QUEUE_IMPL_
#include "queueADT.h"
struct node {
    void* data;
    //size_t num;
    struct node *next;
}node;


typedef struct QueueADT {
    struct node *front;                     /* pointer to front of queue */
    struct node *rear;                      /* pointer to rear of queue  */
    int *contents[ QUEUE_SIZE ];      /* number of items in queue  */
    int *cmprFunc;                    /* The compare function used for insert */
}*QueueADT;






QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) ) {

    struct QueueADT *new;
    new = (struct QueueADT*)malloc(sizeof(struct QueueADT));

    if (cmp == NULL) {
        //do I create a new pointer to the cmp_int64?
        new->front = NULL;
        new->rear = NULL;
        new->cmprFunc = NULL;

    } else {
        new->cmprFunc = &cmp;
        new->front = NULL;
        new->rear = NULL;
    }

    return ( new );
}
```

**Edit 1**
**Error message** went from

```
queueADT.c:22:3: error: 'QueueADT' redeclared as different kind of symbol
 }*QueueADT;
   ^
In file included from queueADT.c:9:0:
queueADT.h:23:21: note: previous declaration of 'QueueADT' was here
 typedef struct { } *QueueADT;
                     ^
queueADT.c:30:1: error: unknown type name 'QueueADT'
 QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) ) {
 ^
```

To

```
In file included from queueADT.c:8:0:
queueADT.h:44:1: error: unknown type name 'QueueADT'
 QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) );
 ^
queueADT.h:49:19: error: unknown type name 'QueueADT'
 void que_destroy( QueueADT queue );


#define QUEUE_SIZE  5
#include "queueADT.h"
#define _QUEUE_IMPL_

struct node {
    void* data;
    //size_t num;
    struct node *next;
}node;


typedef struct QueueADT {
    struct node *front;                     /* pointer to front of queue */
    struct node *rear;                      /* pointer to rear of queue  */
    //int *contents[ QUEUE_SIZE ];      /* number of items in queue  */
    int *cmprFunc;                    /* The compare function used for insert */
}*QueueADT;


QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) ) {

    struct QueueADT *new;
    new = (struct QueueADT*)malloc(sizeof(struct QueueADT));

    if (cmp == NULL) {
        //do I create a new pointer to the cmp_int64?
        new->front = NULL;
        new->rear = NULL;
        new->cmprFunc = NULL;

    } else {
        new->cmprFunc = &cmp;
        new->front = NULL;
        new->rear = NULL;
    }

    return ( new );
}
```

Comment: typedef move to header file(.h). also Probably `node` is typedef'd type.

Comment: Yes I can do that @BLUEPIXY. Note the following answer has been helpful but I still recieve **error message** ` 
In file included from queueADT.c:8:0:
queueADT.h:44:1: error: unknown type name 'QueueADT'
 QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a,const void*b) );
 ^
queueADT.h:49:19: error: unknown type name 'QueueADT'
 void que_destroy( QueueADT queue );`

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding something. I was post as answer the changes as my intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasnt finding the queueStruct was not defined as a type for QueueStruct que_crear was because they weren't being defined in the order listed below

```
typedef struct node {
    void* data;
    struct node *next;
}node;


struct queueStruct {
    struct node *front;                     /* pointer to front of queue */
    struct node *rear;                      /* pointer to rear of queue  */
    int *cmprFunc;
    size_t num;                             /* The compare function used for insert */
};

typedef struct queueStruct *QueueADT;

#define _QUEUE_IMPL_
#include "queueADT.h"
```

so @Drew I did need the single line header but it had to be defined after the struct queueStruct and before queueADT.h

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your C file

```
#ifndef _QUEUE_IMPL_
```

Is incorrect, it should be defining the macro, not testing it:

```
#define _QUEUE_IMPL_
```

---

That being said, there's an easier way to do accomplish what you're trying to do. Instead of your preprocessor wrapping, you can instead have the single line in the header:

```
typedef struct QueueADT *QueueADT;
```

Even if `struct QueueADT` (N.B. this is **different** than `QueueADT`) isn't defined, you can still use a pointer to it. Then, inside your C file, you just define `struct QueueADT`:

```
struct QueueADT
{
    ...
};
```

Note the lack of `typedef` in the `struct` definition.

Comment: alright, so I dont need the name *QueueADT if I define it in the single line header?

Comment: Actually, its even safer to keep the test, and put the definition inside, so that if the definitions get re-included (typically indirectly), the "extra" ones will get skipped.

Comment: @arrowinfedex not sure what you mean - just make the changes I suggested, and everything else should be fine.

Comment: @ScottHunter that's more along the lines of `#include` guards, which surround the entire header.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `#ifndef` near the top of each file?  That is asking "if this symbol isn't defined, include this stuff; otherwise, ignore it".  As the comment says, this is to prevent things from being re-defined.  But in order for it to work, you have to define that symbol within the code block where you make these definitions that you don't want repeated.

Answer (score 0):

**queueADT.h**

```
#ifndef _QUEUE_IMPL_
#define _QUEUE_IMPL_
#define QUEUE_SIZE  5

typedef struct node {
    void* data;
    //size_t num;
    struct node *next;
} node;


typedef struct QueueADT {
    struct node *front;                     /* pointer to front of queue */
    struct node *rear;                      /* pointer to rear of queue  */
    int *contents[ QUEUE_SIZE ];      /* number of items in queue  */
    int *cmprFunc;                    /* The compare function used for insert */
} *QueueADT;

#endif
```